# Passing Batch parameters

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm having a problem with passing parameters to a .bat file. I'm calling it from a java program and passing some parameters, but one of them is a String which I cannot see, I don't know it length and it could have spaces, quotation marks, etc.

For example: `test.bat 05 07 2014 this is "a test" cheers`
And I need to capture them like this:

```
%1: 05
%2: 07
%3: 2014
%4: this is "a test" cheers
```

I can't find a way to do that! :(

Something like `%4 to %last` or `%*` but starting in the 4th parameter.. would be great.

I also tried calling it like:

```
test.bat 05 07 2014 "this is "a test" cheers"
```

Which brings me:

```
%1: 05
%2: 07
%3: 2014
%4: this is "a
%5: test" cheers
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: instead of double quotes try single quotes, also `*` may not work as it is a wildcard character.

Comment: HAve you tried `test.bat 05 07 2014 this is \"a test\"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set $Last=%*
set $Last=!$Last:%1=!
set $Last=!$Last:%2=!
set $Last=!$Last:%3=!
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
echo !$last:~3!
```